# docker bash: npm: command not found after building container

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm building an image with the the below Dockerfile.

But after building, when I run `npm install` it says `bash: npm: command not found`

I have 2 `RUN` commands to build 2 layers, the first one is basically to build the Python environment for the image, including installing `pyodbc` driver and install the necessary packages.

The second layer is to install `node`.

Which step is wrong with the dockerfile?

```yaml
ARG VARIANT=3
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:0-${VARIANT}

# Avoid warnings by switching to noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ARG USERNAME=vscode
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# [Optional] Update UID/GID if needed
RUN if [ "$USER_GID" != "1000" ] || [ "$USER_UID" != "1000" ]; then \
    groupmod --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && usermod --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && chmod -R $USER_UID:$USER_GID /home/$USERNAME; \
    fi


# [Optional] If your requirements rarely change, uncomment this section to add them to the image.
#
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get -y update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools \
    && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile \
    && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc" \
    && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev \
    && pip3 install django-mssql-backend \
    && apt-get install -y libgssapi-krb5-2 \
    && pip3 --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir install -r /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pip-tmp

# ** [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional packages. **
#
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils dialog 2>&1 \
    #
    # Verify git, process tools, lsb-release (common in install instructions for CLIs) installed
    && apt-get -y install git iproute2 procps lsb-release \
    #
    # Install pylint
    #&& pip install pylint \
    #
    # Update Python environment based on requirements.txt
    # && pip --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir install -r /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt \
    # && rm -rf /tmp/pip-tmp \
    #
    # Install node for building front-ends
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install curl gnupg \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x  | bash - \
    && apt-get -y install nodejs \
    #
    # Clean up
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Switch back to dialog for any ad-hoc use of apt-get
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=
```

Comment: share ur complete build  and run commands

Comment: hi @WSMathias9, what do you mean by complete build and run commands? Isn't it the one in the dockerfile above?

Comment: the command used to build this image ex. `docker build -t image:tag .` and `docker run image:tag`

Answer (score 1):

Debian Nodejs could be boguous. Use official nodejs instructions https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall to install nodejs.

Comment: yeap let me try this.

Comment: that's actually what I was doing though. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x  | bash - \
    && apt-get -y install nodejs` and the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you provide your latest Dockerfile ?